# gradle: how to generate a bundle file with dependency=version in it

Tags: gradle

In gradle I would like to generate a "bundle" file - the one with external dependencies and internal modules, like

```
log4j=1.2
my.company.api=1.3
```

So I presume I need to override build task, access dependencies of the root project and iterate over them?
What is the best/most elegant way to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no need to 'replace' build task. You just need to extend it or add another task that will generate the file. Just pick what meets your requirements better. Simple task is elegant enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also look to the gradle-dependency-lock-plugin (https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-dependency-lock-plugin), to generate a bundle file (and use it to lock down your dynamic dependencies)

Comment: Now Gradle 4.8 has inbuilt dependency lock feature!!

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
task bundleFile << {
   new File("$buildDir/runtime.bundle").withWriter { out ->
        configurations.runtime.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { dep -> 
            out.writeLine(dep.moduleVersion.id.toString()) 
      }
   }
}
```